# How do I create new columns from duplicate obeservations and transpose the related data with Python in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column named `Stat` that has duplicate observations. The `Value`column has data respective to the `Stat` column in its same row. How do I create the new columns `name` `loca` and `IDnu` while transposing their respective data from the aforementioned `Value` column?

What I have:

```
     Stat | Value
---------------------
0  | name |   cobras
1  | loca |   DC
2  | IDnu |   2
3  | name |   pythons
4  | loca |   LA
5  | IDnu |   1
```

What I want:

```
   name |loca| IDnu
---------------------
cobras  | DC | 2
pythons | LA | 1
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) and to get index [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
new_df = (df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby('Stat').cumcount(),
                         columns='Stat',
                         values='Value',
                         aggfunc=''.join)
             .rename_axis(columns=None)
             .sort_index(ascending=False ,axis=1)
         )
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
      name loca IDnu
0   cobras   DC    2
1  pythons   LA    1
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

we can agg and then your values into a list, we then pass this into a dictionary to create a new dataframe.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("Stat")["Value"].agg(list).to_dict())
# your column order.
cols = df['Stat'].unique()
```

---

```
print(new_df[cols])
      name loca IDnu
0   cobras   DC    2
1  pythons   LA    1
```